# React native and Redux: Require cycle (how to get rid of it?)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

Working on the backbone of a new RN app, I found myself in the following code state:

- `src/redux/index.ts` (who builds and exports the store) imports `rootReducer` file, to `configureStore` with it.

```js
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  /* middleware definitions */
});
```

- `rootReducer` imports `userReducer` to add it to reducers list with `combineReducers`.

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  /* some reducers */
  user: userReducer,
});
```

- `userReducer` imports `serverApi` to be able to make api calls with thunks.

```js
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/register',
  async ({ country, number }: loginDataType) => {
    const response = await serverApi.post('/register', { country, number });
    return response.data;
  },
);
```

- `serverApi` imports `store` to get the `token` from a user and set it in an Axios interceptor.

```js
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    const { token } = store.getState().user;
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
);
```

And store is exported in `src/redux/index.ts` as I said. There you go, this is the cycle. React throws me a warning like, come on man, don't do that. Where did I go wrong or what could I do differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the docs actually give the answer to this use case.

https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files

Basically instead of importing the store in the api file, we inject it from the store file itself :

```
export const injectStore(_store) {
  store = _store
}
```

And in the store file :

```
injectStore(store);
```